# JavaScript: Differences in using "--" vs "- 1" to decrement a for loop's arr.length

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, return, decrement

I'm curious as to why I get two different results when decrementing the arr.length with arr.length-- and arr.length - 1.  I would have thought these would have functioned the same.  For example:

```
const numbers = [10, 20, 40, 30, 50]

function solution(numbers) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1]) {
          console.log('TRUE: ' + numbers[i]+" is increasing to "+ numbers[i+1])
       } else {
         return console.log('FALSE: ' + numbers[i] +' is decreasing to ' + numbers[i+1])
       }
    }
}
```

logs out as:

```
"TRUE: 10 is increasing to 20"
"TRUE: 20 is increasing to 40"
"FALSE: 40 is decreasing to 30"
```

but when I swap in a decrement:

`(let i = 0; i < numbers.length--; i++)`

the else returns undefined

```
"TRUE: 10 is increasing to 20"
"TRUE: 20 is increasing to 40"
"FALSE: undefined is decreasing to undefined"
```

Comment: They're two different things. `numbers.length--` *changes* the value of `numbers.length`, while `numbers.length - 1` does not.

Comment: For the `length` property, decreasing it also has the effect of removing items from the end of the array. Is that what you're aiming to do? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: `something--` is shorthand for `something = something - 1`, so it updates the variable.

Comment: I don't understand why they gave -1 to the question when it is a valid question. ‍♂️

Comment: @Brian well it is a valid question, but basic JavaScript syntax is extremely well-documented on the Internet, and a quick search would have saved the OP the time of typing in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
console.log(numbers)
```

You'll see that every loop, the `numbers` array loses the last value. In JavaScript, array lengths are mutable. You can essentially delete every element in the array by doing `array.length = 0`.

The `--` is the decrement operator, which not only subtracts `1` from the value of `numbers.length`, but also sets the value of `numbers.length` to `numbers.length - 1`.

If you want to control the for-loop correctly, you will always use `i < numbers.length - 1`, otherwise each loop, you are actually deleting the last element of the array.